# Determine the Number of Multiples of Given Numbers $\le$ 1000

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

For one of the problems I am currently trying to solve, I am to determine the number of multiples of 3, 5 and 7 that are between 0 and 1000. Also, I am to do the same for each combination of the three numbers which would then include:

$$
M(n_1, n_2, ..., n_m) \text{ - Number of multiples of } n_i \text{ between 0 and 1000} \\
M(3) = ? \\
M(5) = ? \\
M(7) = ? \\
M(3, 5) = ? \\
M(3, 7) = ? \\
M(5, 7) = ? \\
M(3, 5, 6) = ?
$$

Is there an equation that I can use to determine this and if so, how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go for solving this question would be to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Here, $$M(3,5,7) = M(3) + M(5) + M(7) - M(3,5) - M(5,7) - M(3,7) + M(3,5,7)$$ where $M(a,b,… z)$ indicates the number of common multiples between a given range of numbers of $a,b,…z$.

Comment: But how do I know how many multiples of a number there are between the given range?

Comment: @OmariCelestine See here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-number-of-multiples-of-a-given-number-between-a-range-of-numbers